# Jquery selector is a variable?

Tags: jquery, variables, caching, selector

I want to create variables for each part of the css, however I noticed there is a problem. When I want to dynamically refer to a selector with the variable I created earlier, I've no idea how to write it.

For example:

```
var defaultAppend = $("p");
var selectFirstDesignerLi = $(".template-seasonFinder .designersToShow li a[data-X=defaultAppend.html()]");
```

Notice I've reused "defaultAppend" with .html() method added, apparently writing this way will not work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use string concatenation like `...a[data-X="+defaultAppend.html()+"]...`

```
var selectFirstDesignerLi = $(".template-seasonFinder .designersToShow li a[data-X="+defaultAppend.html()+"]");
```